# How to get value of SymbolicLinkList from IoGetDeviceInterfaces routine?

Tags: c++, winapi, driver, minifilter, kernel-mode

I am developing mini-filter. I use [`IoGetDeviceInterfaces()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get device interface instances.

1. When I check the status of this routine, It is success
2. When I check SymbolicLinkList parameter, It is NOT NULL
3. But when I print value of SymbolicLinkList to log, It does not show any thing.

How can I get value of SymbolicLinkList parameter from this routine?

This is my code:

```
status = IoGetDeviceInterfaces(&deviceGuid, NULL, 0, &symbolicLinkList);
if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
     if (symbolicLinkList == NULL)
        DbgPrint("IoGetDeviceInterfaces symbolicLinkList is NULL\n");
     else 
     {
         DbgPrint("IoGetDeviceInterfaces: %ws\n", symbolicLinkList);
         DbgPrint("IoGetDeviceInterfaces: %wZ\n", symbolicLinkList);
         DbgPrint("IoGetDeviceInterfaces: %s\n", symbolicLinkList);
         DbgPrint("IoGetDeviceInterfaces: %ws\n", symbolicLinkList);
         DbgPrint("IoGetDeviceInterfaces: %p\n", symbolicLinkList);
     }
} else {
    DbgPrint("IoGetDeviceInterfaces is failed\n");
}
```

The log is like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you at IRQL = PASSIVE_LEVEL ?

Comment: "If no device interface instances match the search criteria, this routine returns STATUS_SUCCESS and the string contains a single NULL character."  In other words, an empty string, which is consistent with the debug output.

Comment: How to check **`IRQL = PASSIVE_LEVEL`**? I just want to know the value, struct and format of SymbolicLinkList. My purpose is get the unique name of drive from GUID (vendor id, product id, ..), so I try to do this.

Comment: What type do you have for `symbolicLinkList` now? [MSDN says what the expected format of that out parameter should be](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): it writes out a pointer to some strings. Therefore, `symbolicLinkList` should be a `WCHAR *` and you pass a pointer to *that* to `IoGetDeviceInterfaces()`. However, you should check the other comments here as well.

Comment: @andlabs I use **`PWSTR symbolicLinkList;`**. In MSDN, `SymbolicLinkList` of `IoGetDeviceInterfaces()` is said that: `A pointer to a wide character pointer to which the routine, if successful, writes the base address of a buffer that contains a list of Unicode strings.` How can I get each Unicode string from this list?

Comment: You should really know what IRQL you are running at, but you can verify it by calling KeGetCurrentIrql.  But I think the function is probably just returning an empty list, so you need to check whether `*symbolicLinkList == L'\0'`

Comment: @HarryJohnston `*symbolicLinkList == L'\0'` is TRUE. It is empty list. Thanks all.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I always get `*symbolicLinkList == L'\0'` for all drives although the status is success. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with that technology ... but the documentation for IoGetDeviceInterfaces says that the GUID has to be a class GUID which doesn't seem to be the case in your code.